# Concatenating a string and primary key Id while inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user table in mysql, I insert data like this:

```
    /* prepare query */
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `users`(`first_name`, 
                                `last_name`, 
                                `gender`, 
                                `username`, 
                                `profile_picture`, 
                                `provider`, 
                                `provider_id`, 
                                `provider_username`,
                                `provider_profile`, 
                                `provider_profile_picture`,
                                `last_login`, 
                                `created_date`, 
                                `ip_address`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), INET_ATON(?))'; 

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if($stmt){

 $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $user['first_name'], 
                                     $user['last_name'], 
                                     $user['gender'], 
                                     $user['username'], 
                                     $user['profile_picture'], 
                                     $user['provider'],
                                     $user['id'], 
                                     $user['username'], 
                                     $user['link'],
                                     $user['profile_picture'],                                     
                                     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  $stmt->execute();
 /* Execute the statement */
```

I would like to make the `username` be equal to `'user'` + `userId` which is autoincremental primary key field.

so that the usernames get in order:

```
user1
user2
user3 and so forth
```

what is a slick way to accomplish that?

Comment: There is not a slick way.  To actually set the value, you would need a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff any pointers for that?

Comment: . . I was sort of hoping you would think "Oh, a trigger, that's too complicated".  The place to start is with the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: it does sound complex for something I thought would be simple, but @bill is saying trigger wont work with auto-increment. hmm should I better drop this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `user_id` is an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, then you can't do this with a single statement, even if you use a trigger.

The problem is that the AUTO_INCREMENT value isn't generated until after the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger runs, but you can't change `username` in the `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

So you just have to do the `INSERT`, then immediately do an `UPDATE`.

If `user_id` is *not* an AUTO_INCREMENT, but instead is something you specify yourself, then it's easy, you just do the concatenation in your PHP code before you pass the values as parameters.

---

Update: You can't do it with MySQL 5.7 generated columns either. It results in this error when you try to create the table:

> Generated column 'username' cannot refer to auto-increment column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the username is **always** 'user' + userid, the slickest way I can think of to do this is to have a table with everything except `username` in it, and a view on top of that table that adds `username`.  You would then do any inserts and updates on the table, and any selects that require `username` could be done on the view.

```
CREATE VIEW userview AS 
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, profile_picture, provider, 
       provider_id, provider_username, provider_profile, provider_profile_picture,
       last_login, created_date, ip_address, 'user' + user_id as username
FROM USER
```