# MySQL auto increment date time id with prefix

Tags: c#, mysql

i need help to insert table with auto increment id, i have been looking around but still couldn't figure it out.

i need to insert my primary like this **06092017-001**(with auto-increment)
i already try trigger like this but it doesn't do anything

```
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON table_test
FOR EACH ROW SET @id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d%m%y'),@id);
```

need help to fix this trigger or any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want id to run from 1 - 999 daily? Or start at 1 every new day?

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331194/concatenating-a-string-and-primary-key-id-while-inserting