# how to output a parameter using a stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables say

table1:

```
create table Person(
  Id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(20),
  Gender char(1)
);
```

table2:

```
create table Details(
  Age int,
  Phone int(10) primary key,
  Address varchar(100)
  Id foreign key(Id) references Person(Id),
  Name foreign key(Name) references Person(Name)
);
```

i will have to create a stored procedure to insert data into table:'Details'

```
create procedure usp_insert(
  IN Name varchar(100),
  IN Age int,
  IN Phone int(10),
  IN Address varchar(100),
  OUT Id int
)
begin

//want to output the Id as QW001 on inserting the data into the Details table.

insert into Details(Name,Age,Phone,Address) values(name,age,phone,address)
end
```

How can i achieve the Id in the following format 'QW001' as output parameter.
Can someone help me out in correcting the above stored procedure,since i'm new to this. Any help is appreciated.
TYIA!

Comment: MySQL auto-increment columns are integers only. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331194/concatenating-a-string-and-primary-key-id-while-inserting/23331246#23331246

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  LAST_INSERT_ID() like this :

```
create procedure usp_insert(
  IN Name varchar(100),
  IN Age int,
  IN Phone int(10),
  IN Address varchar(100),
  OUT Id int
)
begin

insert into Details(Name,Age,Phone,Address) values(name,age,phone,address);
set Id =CONCAT("QW00", LAST_INSERT_ID()) AS ConcatenatedString;
end
```

Comment: But I wanted the Id to be in the following format 'QW001'

Comment: Is there any other way I can concat or something?

Comment: you can use CONCAT() function of mysql

Comment: Will this id get inserted whenever a new row is added to the table?

Comment: the id you put out from the procedure is a concat from the primary_key and the text . if you want to save in another  table is a different request.please explain better what you want to do

Comment: I want it as a new column

Comment: if this new column is varchar you can concat() this value and then use SET function for save the value in a variable and then do an insert.